# JavaScript Object: Cannot add new property to Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I simply want to add another property that display course name when enrollments for a user are grabbed.

```
router.get('/enrollments/courses/me', auth, async (req,res)=>{
    user_id = req.user._id
    try{
        let Courses = await Enrollment.find({user_id})
        for(x in Courses){
            if(!Courses[x].course_id){
                throw new Error("No enrollments found for this student.")
            }
             courseName = await Course.findById(Courses[x].course_id)
             Courses[x].course_name = courseName.Course_Name
             console.log(Courses[x])
        }
        res.status(201).send(Courses)
    }catch(e){
        res.status(400).send(e)
    }
})
```

Example:
Courses =

```
[
    {
        "_id": "607768e5e8105058546f658a",
        "user_id": "606e476107a74d49c4757c1f",
        "course_id": "60722e7392d7c6539c344a83",
        "createdAt": "2021-04-14T22:12:53.527Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-04-14T22:12:53.527Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "60777e7d6b2bff6040f46f58",
        "user_id": "606e476107a74d49c4757c1f",
        "course_id": "60722e8b92d7c6539c344a86",
        "createdAt": "2021-04-14T23:45:01.881Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-04-14T23:45:01.881Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "607787ec9f21525d644855a8",
        "user_id": "606e476107a74d49c4757c1f",
        "course_id": "60722e8392d7c6539c344a85",
        "createdAt": "2021-04-15T00:25:16.734Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-04-15T00:25:16.734Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "6078d78ea1ee7f05f89a3c17",
        "user_id": "606e476107a74d49c4757c1f",
        "course_id": "60722e6b92d7c6539c344a82",
        "createdAt": "2021-04-16T00:17:18.941Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-04-16T00:17:18.941Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

courseName =

```
{
  "_id" : "60722e6b92d7c6539c344a82",
  "Course_Name" : "Course_1",
  "Description" : "This is my 1rst course",
  "__v" : 0
}
```

I loop through each enrollment and make another call to grab the Course name and add it to each object like so

```
Courses[x].course_name = courseName.Course_Name
```

The course name does not appear when I return Courses

I can do this :

```
Courses[x].course_id = courseName.Course_Name
```

and the course name appears for the course_id, but obviously I don't want to do that.
This is how Ive added new properties to an Object before, why is this method not working?

Comment: Looks correct to me. How are you fetching this? Can you show the client side code where you observe the missing added field?

Comment: @ChristianFritz Essentially I just get the array Courses Objects return the way it displays above. the course_name property never appears. I know Im grabbing everything else correctly since I can assign courseName to an existing property in the object, but not instantiate any new ones.

Comment: silly question, but was is `Courses`? Are you using mongoose?

Comment: @Christian Fritz yes I'm using mongoose. That's a schema I built.

Comment: so it's not a plain object, is it?

Comment: @Patryk Cieszkowski when I checked the return type it said object.

Comment: @Ken well, because it is an object, just not a plain object. It's an instance of the mongoose document, it's `.toJSON()` method returns a plain object based on your document schema. Try converting `Courses` to JSONs and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is due to the way mongoose converts Documents to json, which is implicit when you pass the Courses object to the `res.send` function. If you first make the courses plain objects, you should be able to get predictable results:

```js
  ...
  let Courses = await Enrollment.find({user_id})
  Courses = Courses.map(x => x.toJSON())
  ...
```

---

Update:

As Patryk pointed out, it seems that Mongoose provides its own mechanism for doing just that: [`.lean`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-lean). In that case this maybe be all you need:

```js
  let Courses = await Enrollment.find({user_id}).lean()
```

Comment: I havent used mongoose in a bit, but wouldn't adding `.lean()` to the query be enough?

Comment: .lean() did the trick. Thank you all so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As Christian & Patryk pointed out correctly,

"Courses" in your case will be an instance of mongoose.Document. You need to convert it into a native javascript object to be able to add new properties to it using -

```
Courses = Courses.toJSON();
```

or

```
Courses = Courses.toObject();
```

then you can add new property using,

```
Object.defineProperty(Courses[x], "course_name", {value : 'some value'});
```

or

```
Courses[x].course_name = courseName.Course_Name;
```